# Managing Database Access for MicroServices

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, microservices, web-api

We currently have a work stream where we are splitting out a Monolith into microservices and there has been a debate as to how we will access and persist data.

To give you a good idea of how most of our apps are being set up, we have an app built strictly for the UI, a Web API it talks to and then another Web API that, that API talks to that manage access to the database.

While it definitely seems appealing to have a Web API that we use to manages access to the database, we still have to build out endpoints specific to each app and, for the most part, the Web API our UI App talks to just acts as a proxy.

Also, there is no real design pattern set forth, do we just use our Web API as a proxy, or do we set up multiple endpoints in the data layer API and consume all of those to create our own DTOs?

This is a C# project and we typically use Entity Framework, so to me, it seems like using a Database First approach to generate our Entities in our Web API makes a lot more sense. That way we aren't managing migrations in multiple projects.

It seems too late in the game to separate our database into multiple databases, which is something I would prefer.

Comment: Just to be quite sure, what exactly do you mean when you say "Web API"? Do you mean that for one "microservice", you have one service which handles incoming external request, and one service which is only used by the first one to access the database?

Comment: That's correct, with one exception the service to access the database was originally built to handle external requests, which it will continue to do. I'm not entirely sure if we plan on just making this a service to access the database.

Comment: What does the intermediate service actually do of use in this scenario? Wouldn’t it be simpler for the UI to just call the service that actually has data access?

Comment: Yes, that is what I believe, but for whatever reason there is an internal push to use it as a proxy...

Comment: Honestly, your situation seems a bit weird to me. A microservice is already small enough to be self contained, and you absolutely don't want to expose its internals (such as database access) to other services. Thus, I don't see the point of creating another application so that the "front-end" service can talk to the "data access" service. It just adds useless overhead. Do you know why your colleagues are pushing for this design?

Comment: The number one reason was to avoid having issues with the schema changing and another services entities not being updated to reflect that change. Supposedly having a service that we call into means we don't need to know anything about the data access layer and we can call the API and expect the same results... Although to me this just leads to a slew of other issues.

Comment: What do you mean, "_another service entities not being updated_"? Entities for the microservice A will **never** be used by the microservice B. If B requires data from A, then B will ask them through the public API of A.

Comment: part of the issue is that these microservices basically do the same thing, they don't offer different solutions, the plan is to use the new API layer to proxy to the old API layer so we don't have to rewrite the persistence layer. A call from the Web App to the Web Api will look like this: Web App: GetTestObjects -> New Api Layer: GetTestObjects -> Legacy API Layer: GetTestObjects... Its very redudant

Comment: To make things worse is that these calls aren't set up yet, so will have to build two API layers simultaneously, one basically having no real use.

Comment: I'm having troubles grasping your use case. When you have a monolith that you want to split into microservices, you first isolate a small part you want to extract just as if it was a stand-alone application (from the API to the DAL), then you extract it to a different application (e.g. as an independent web service), which the monolith then calls remotely. It seems to me you're trying to work your way backward: creating a service which exposes a public API but uses the monolith as data access. This is useless, you've just increased complexity for none of the benefits.

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth on this, it was a difficult use case to explain, but the last comment has definitely helped to clear things up a lot for me. I do believe that, that is the appropriate solution to what we need to do. If you add that as the answer I will accept, thanks again!

Comment: If the aim of good design is to create high cohesion (put code together that regards the same topic) and low coupling (modularity, low impact of change), then this will likely create the opposite effect. The code dealing with one aspect (or bounded context) of your overall system is now split among three code bases. Your microservices are temporally coupled, as for each to work at all the others beneath it must be running. In addition, they are tightly coupled by interface, as changes to entities and fields must, by necessity, cascade up and down the chain.

Comment: (I wish someone combined an answer from comments by VincentSavard and MrCochese above; I'd upvote it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the process to migrate a monolith to a microservice architecture involves carefully extracting parts from the monolith so they can live as stand-alone applications. For example, let's consider a hotel booking system. You have a rental subsystem to allocate rooms, a profile subsystem to persist data about your customers, a billing subsystem, and so on<sup>1</sup>. This is our starting point.

The monolith most likely evolved organically for a months or years, and all subsystems are not as decoupled as you would wish. From a microservice perspective, this is bad. Our first step will be to take one of those subsystems (usually, the least risky) and to re-architecture it *inside the monolith* so that it is completely decoupled. In our example, this could possibly be the profile subsystem.

Data access to the customer data is spread everywhere in our code. Our first task is to isolate this subsystem. We'll move the code to a separate library which will expose an interface through which the other subsystems will request data about customers. This is very important: no other subsystem can ask the database directly about customer data. They **have** to ask the service for this information.

Once this step is done<sup>2</sup>, the subsystem is ready to be moved to its own service to live on his own. In what's left of the monolith, now, instead of using the library to access customer data, we will call the new stand-alone profile service<sup>3</sup>. We have our first microservice<sup>4</sup>.

We accomplished two very important things:

1. The microservice has **high cohesion**. Everything related to customer data is now isolated in its own microservice. All changes to the way customer data is persisted, and how customer business rules are applied are scoped to a single service;
2. There is **low coupling** between the new microservice and the rest of the code. When we change how we persist customer data, the rental subsystem is completely unaffected. Which is a good thing: it shouldn't care about this, it only cares about rentals.

Back to your use case, it seems to me you are working your way backward. By building "microservices" in front of the monolith to proxy calls, you have created two important problems.

1. You reduced the cohesion of your system. New features will most likely require changes in the proxy service to alter the API, then changes to the monolith to support this new API.
2. You increased the coupling between the two services, because you now have to change both of them for every feature.

You're not gaining the benefits of a microservice architecture, but you still increased the complexity of the system as a whole. Your monolith is still just a big, it's still costly to run your entire test suites and involve QA for every bug fix or feature and you cannot make progress as fast as you would like.

<sub>1. In domain-driven design, these subsystems would certainly be bounded contexts.</sub>
<sub>2. Even though you could extract the subsystem to a separate service right away, it's probably a good idea to wait until its public interface has stabilized through a few features. Once it's extracted to a new microservice, it may be costly to fix mistakes due to placing boundaries incorrectly.</sub>
<sub>3. This means that even though you may actually use the same instance of a DBMS for all your services, the database of the service A *should not be coupled* to the database of the service B. For instance, if you had a `customer` table and a `rental` table and had a foreign key `customer.id` in `rental`, you will have to delete this foreign key and *lose this referential integrity* enforced by the DBMS. You'll have to ensure consistency in another way. It's the price to pay in a microservice architecture.</sub>
<sub>4. Obviously, I omitted a lot of infrastructure complexity from this answer. Doing microservices isn't a low hanging fruit: make sure it's actually appropriate to your use case!</sub>

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, thanks for teaching me about the `<sup>` tag for footnotes! :)